React, cookies installed by the server disappear asp.net after updating the page
I'm on the server side asp.net after authorization, I set http only cookies, and my react client accepts them, but after refreshing the page, this cookie disappears. What should I do about it, because if I make requests through postman, then the cookies do not disappear there, but they disappear in react.

The problem was that React runs on http, not https.
